# ANDROID: Query Network Band frequency information

Tags: android, networking, testing, frequency, gsm

I need a way to determine which cellular network band my phone is currently on, and which tower it is connected to.

How would I go about doing this? I know there is a "Service Mode" you can enter with the command *#0011# --> however this does not work on my phone.

If there is a way to create an application where I can get this information, that would be ideal. I believe I would need to access the internal telephony classes of the android OS - which can be accessed via reflection.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at these:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/gsm/GsmCellLocation.html

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/TelephonyManager.html

You can get the CellID with appropriate methods within these classes. The CellID is a unique number for each cell (or each sector) so that identifies the tower. But relating that number with a specific tower (that is, its location) is harder, as that usually is not public information.

I'm not sure if you can get the frequency band, but if the "cell info" methods mentioned in the above links include channel numbers ([ARFCN](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Absolute_radio-frequency_channel_number)), you can deduce the band from those numbers.